# Changing value of a variable in the file to be imported; Freemarker

Tags: java, import, macros, freemarker

File `testMacro.txt`

```
<#import "./importMe.txt" as my>

<#assign a=0 >
<@my.macro1 />
${a}
```

File `importMe.txt`

```
<#macro macro1 >
${a}
</#macro>
```

Now from java file, when I execute it it says.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression a is undefined on line 3, column 3 in importMe.txt at msjava.hdom.examples.DbQuery.main(DbQuery.java:59)
Caused by: freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression a is undefined on line 3, column 3 in importMe.txt`

But if I dont do the import but instead define the macro inside the file `testMacro.txt` then it works fine.

What I want to do is that I want to change the value `a` in the file `testMacro.txt` , within the file `importMe.txt`, such that it gets reflected later in the `testMacro.txt`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important point of `#import` is exactly that it prevents interferences among the templates by giving them their own namespaces. So that's why it doesn't work. If you want the templates to share that variable, use a global variable: `<#global a = 0>` instead of `#assign`. Or, you can set the variable in the imported namespace like `<#assign a = 0 in my>`.

Comment: Is not there any pass by reference kind of thing in freemarker functions?

Comment: There isn't. However, Java objects are passed by reference, so with mutable objects you can do some tricks.